# Creating a Javascript object to hold user's geolocation co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I would like to create a Javascript object, let's name it 'geoloc' and place it inside a Javascript library I have created.

This object will use the html5 geolocation API to store the `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` values of the user's location into two object properties, let's name them `geoloc.latitude` and `geoloc.longitude`.

Then I can use them inside my html code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.writeln('Your latitude is: ', geoloc.latitude);
    document.writeln('Your longitude is: ', geoloc.longitude); 
</script>
```

I already tried:

```
<a href="http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation">this</a>
```

but it displays an alert; I need object variables returned to my html code instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of alert does it display? Is it a geolocation permission confirmation? If so, you cannot avoid it - the user must permit the user agent to query their location.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean simply creating a JS object to store your info?

```
function geoloc(latitude, longitude)
{
    this.latitude=latitude;
    this.longitude=longitude;
}
```

Then instantiate it like so:

```
var userLocation = new geoloc(lat, lon);
```

This shows you how to get lat and long using Google API

http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/geo_js/sample.html

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to change is the code in the displayPosition function.  Instead of alert'ing it out to the user, store the values in variables and use them wherever you want.

```
mycode = {
     lat: null,
     lon: null
};

function displayPosition(position) {
     mycode.lat = position.coords.latitude;
     mycode.lon = position.coords.longitude;
}
```